# Unable to properly read integers from input via fgets()

Tags: c, input, int, fgets

I am currently practicing reading input from the user, and I am using fgets to read the input, but there seems to be a problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int N = 0;
    char ar[2];
    fgets(ar, 2, stdin);
    N = atoi(ar);
     char arr[N][22];

    // for loop automatically runs automatically
    for(int i = 0; i< N; i++){ 
            printf("i is %d\n", i);
            fgets(arr[i], 22, stdin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

First, I read an integer using fgets and I employ atoi to convert it into an integer. Then using that integer, I loop N times, however for some reason it seems that there is some stuff still left in the input stream and it is causing my for loop to automatically run two times.

EDIT:

**input:**

5

**output (automatically):**

i is 0

i is 1

Comment: if I input 5 for example, the for loop will run two times automatically for some reason.

Comment: To read integers use `scanf` instead.

Comment: I have updated my post with an "edit" to show an example

Comment: your array too small . at least `char ar[3];` (because for include newline)

Comment: Note that the array `char ar[2];` can only contain a single character (presumably that's intended to be a digit) plus a terminal null.  You should be using a bigger buffer size — `char ar[4096];` for example — to read the line, and then you can use `atoi()` on  it.  As it stands, you leave a newline in the buffer, so the next `fgets()` inside the loop is going to read the newline without waiting for you to type anything more.  You should be testing the return from `fgets()` each time you use it.  You should validate `N` before using it to declare your VLA (variable length array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input array isn't big enough.

If you enter a single digit number, that digit and a newline are in the input buffer.  Then `fgets` reads 1 character (i.e. 2 - 1) into the buffer (because that's all that will fit) and adds the null terminator.  So the newline is left in the buffer.

Make the `ar` buffer big enough to store any number you might enter plus room the the newline.  A size of 10 should be good enough.